# Resizing window done with Perl Tk causes scrollbars, text to disappear

Tags: perl, resize, window, tk-toolkit, perltk

Working on some Perl/Tk code at work for coloring and displaying pre-written code files. The program is coloring and displaying just fine. My only problem is that if I then re-size the window smaller, the scrollbars and text windows disappear, rather than dynamically resizing to fit the new window size. Is there a way to fix my code so that the scrollbars, text areas and such will remain fully viewable upon resizing? Thanks for any help you can give.

The text to be displayed is parsed and then passed as the variable $macro. I have left out the subroutines for parsing the text and the code for colorizing as it seems to be working fine and does not contain any formatting instructions so I highly doubt it will be involved in the resizing problem. Here is my code:

```
my $mw = ( MainWindow->new );

$mw->Button(
    -text    => "Close Window",
    -command => sub {exit}
    )->grid(
    -row        => 2,
    -column     => 2,
    -columnspan => 4,
    -sticky     => "nsew",
    -padx       => 3,
    -pady       => 3
    );

$mw->title("MacroView $arg");

my $fullpathbar = $mw->Label(
    -textvariable => \$fullpath,
    -font         => "{Courier} 12 {normal}"
    )->grid(
    -row        => 0,
    -column     => 0,
    -columnspan => 5,
    -sticky     => "nsew",
    -padx       => 3,
    -pady       => 3
    );

my $tb = $mw->Scrolled( "Text", -font => "{Courier} 12 {normal}" )->grid(
    -row        => 1,
    -column     => 0,
    -columnspan => 6,
    -sticky     => "nsew",
    -padx       => 3,
    -pady       => 3
);

my $rw = $mw->Label(
    -textvariable => \$rwtext,
    -font         => "{Courier} 12 {normal}"
    )->grid(
    -row    => 2,
    -column => 0,
    -sticky => "nsew",
    -padx   => 3,
    -pady   => 3
    );

my $scrollbar = $mw->Scrollbar( -orient => 'horizontal' );

$scrollbar->configure( -command => [ 'xview', $fullpathbar ] );

$scrollbar->grid(
    -row    => 0,
    -column => 5,
    -sticky => "nsew",
    -padx   => 3,
    -pady   => 3
);

$tb->insert( 'end', $macro );

$tb->configure( -state => 'disabled' );

MainLoop;
```

EDIT: The solution was to add the following lines of code before the invocation of MainLoop;

```
my $columns;
my $rows;
my $i;

($columns, $rows) = $mw->gridSize();
for ($i=0;$i<$columns;$i++){
  $mw->gridColumnconfigure($i, -weight=>1);
}
for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
  $mw->gridRowconfigure($i, -weight=>1);
}
```